# Get all groups from a long line

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, findall

I have the following string:

`aaa<a class="c-item_foot" href="/news/a/">11r11</a></div>bbb<a class="c-item_foot" href="/news/b/">222</a></div>ccgc<a class="c-item_foot" href="/news/c/">3333a333</a></div>ddd<a class="c-item_foot" href="/news/d/">44a444444</a></div>eee`

I try to get the following values from this line:

- 11r11
- 222
- 3333a333
- 44a444444

In other words, to get the values between `<a class="c-item_foot" href="/news/*/">` and `</a></div>`. I'm trying to get it in the following way:

```py
text=open("./string.txt","r").read()
print(u'\n'.join(re.findall(r"<a class=\"c-item_foot.*>(.*)</a></div>", text)))
```

But only get the last group `44a444444`. Can anyone show me the correct example?

Comment: Looks like `[^<>]+(?=</a>)` https://regex101.com/r/jrP8Ax/1

Comment: make it ungreedy  `<a class=\"c-item_foot.*?>(.*?)</a></div>`

Comment: Remember not to [parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Why you can't use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)? `soup = BeautifulSoup("your_str", 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.text)`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a html parsing library like BeautifulSoup.

```
html_doc = 'aaa<a class="c-item_foot" href="/news/a/">11r11</a></div>bbb<a class="c-item_foot" href="/news/b/">222</a></div>ccgc<a class="c-item_foot" href="/news/c/">3333a333</a></div>ddd<a class="c-item_foot" href="/news/d/">44a444444</a></div>eee'
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
values = [tag.text for tag in soup.find_all('a')]
```

Comment: Depending on rest of html (if there is more...) using class is certainly faster and likely more selective.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right approach, but you have to use the `lazy` evaluation method for regex. Try this instead:

`<a class=\"c-item_foot.*?>(.*?)<\/a><\/div>`

You can play with regex here: https://regex101.com/r/pggVVJ/1

Answer (score 0):

Python has an HTML parser that delivers what you expect in this case.

The html.parser documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html).

﻿

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = []
        self.a_tag = None

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "a":
            self.a_tag = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.a_tag:
            self.data.append(data)
            self.a_tag = False

string = """aaa<a class="c-item_foot" href="/news/a/">11r11</a></div>bbb<a class="c-item_foot" href="/news/b/">222</a></div>ccgc<a class="c-item_foot" href="/news/c/">3333a333</a></div>ddd<a class="c-item_foot" href="/news/d/">44a444444</a></div>eee"""
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(string)
print(parser.data)

OUTPUT:

['11r11', '222', '3333a333', '44a444444']
```